# Simple tkinter file path reader is not working

Tags: python, tkinter, path

I'm new to tkinter and I want to read in a file. This simple operation turns out to be non-trivial. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg \
    import FigureCanvasTkAgg  ### PROBLEM 1: REMOVING THIS IMPORT CAUSES AN  
                              ### ERROR WHEN OPENING THE DIALOG


def op():
    global filename
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()


root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open file", command=op).grid(column=0, row=1)
#print(filename)     ### PROBLEM 2: UNCOMMENTING THIS CAUSES AN ERROR
                     ### UNLESS I ADD <filename = ""> ABOVE THE op
                     ### FUNCTION DEFINITION
root.mainloop()
```

Questions:

1) It seems **very** weird that importing a totally different package, matplotlib, actually has an influence over whether my program works or not. Without that import, clicking on the opening button causes an error. With it, it works fine.
Could this be a bug?

2) Why is `filename` not accessible outside the function body, even though I'm declaring it global? A minimal working example that has the same structure as my tkinter code is this - and this works:

```
def test():
    global testname
    testname = 23


def call_test():
    test()


call_test()
print(testname)
```

Oddly enough, I can get my tkinter code to not produce an error, if I insert  a `filename = ""` at the top - but I still can't actually *print out* the filename, it's just that the error disappears.

3) Is there any other, more elegant way to access the path of the file I'm opening without using global variables? What is the best practice?

Comment: You may want to see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/184589/152065.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

I don't think it's fair to call [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) *"...a totally different package..."*, let alone calling `backend_tkagg` that. Internally the second import also imports `filedialog`. That's why you don't need it. You can replace the second import simply with:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
```

---

## 2

At the time which:

```
print(filename)
```

is executed `filename` simply *does not exist* as `op` was never called before. Python isn't compiled, it is interpreted, it simply skips runtime error(s) until the lines that cause it are *run*. Try:

```
op()
print(filename)
```

to see the difference.

---

## 3

Your file path reader *does* work. It's just you try to `print` the `filepath` before it starts to exist, or before it has a path in it.

I think another way in the context would be:

```
...
def op():
    global root
    root.filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(root.filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I'm still stuck with 3: the problem is, if I use your approach, that instead of the tkinter window appearing, the open file dialog appears, no matter where I put `filename = op()`. What I'd like is to store the file name in the `filename` variable, but not have tkinter make the file open window appear when I execute `filename = op()`

Comment: You can hardcode the file path like `filename = c:/users/.../file.py` but then you'll be unable to select a file?

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the file. All I want is a variable in which to store the path of a file I select from the window that opens (your solution does that - but unfortunately it messes up my GUI, because suddenly the file selection dialog appears when I run the program, not when I click the button). I'm suprised getting the file path, without touching the GUI, is so hard to do.

Comment: Your own code does that already. You simply need to answer _when_ to print the file path and _what_ to print when there isn't a file?

Comment: I'm not sure it does.  If I uncomment `#print(filename)`, and put a `filename = ""` and the top to cover the case of no filename, run the program and click on any file, the console shows nothing...

Comment: Your recent edit works - but I'd like to be able to print the file path not from inside `op` but from outside of it. Also, I'm confused when you say "It's just you try to print the filepath before it starts to exist, or before it has a path in it." Since I run `print(filename)` after `tk.Button(...)` shouldn't it only be printed after I press the button? I think I'm confused by the order of command in event-driven programming.

Comment: @nicht No. `tk.Button(...)` accepts the reference of the function you're using. So at the time, it is read, the function isn't called. So it moves on directly to the next line which has an undefined variable as the function wasn't called yet, at the button wasn't pressed yet.

Comment: But the problem remains, if I do press the button and click on a file, `print(filename)` still doesn't print anything (as stated my comment before the last one).

Comment: @nicht The console shows nothing (in fact it shows an empty string), because at the time which the print statement is called, it is an empty string. Because it is called _before_ the file was selected.

Comment: Sorry for my (perhaps naive) question, but shouldn't once the file is selected, the filename variable be updated, so that the `print(filename)` statement shows the correct value? Also, I think in your edit you mean `print(root.filename)` ?

Comment: @nicht The print statement is run only _once_, and that is _BEFORE_ the file selection can be done with a button click, hence `filename` is empty.